# Which is faster, or less CPU Cycle to be used in Integer Multiply? ex: 2 * 2 and 123456789 * 123456789

Tags: integer, cpu

Will 2 * 2 be faster than 123456789 * 123456789 ?
Is it less CPU Cycle to be used?